# jQuery external links class

Tags: jquery

I have implemented the following in to one of our sites to show an external link icon next to external links:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#extlinks a').filter(function() {
 return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
  }).after(' <img src="/images/external.png" alt="external link"/>');
});
```

We use Business Catalyst and I hope it is not something to do with the way their servers are set up but, if you remove the www from the url ALL links show as external.

Here's an example: http://noosabiosphere.org.au/_blog/Environment_Blog

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure links start with http:// I've tested it with following links:

```
<ul style="list-style:none none outside;">
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/EnterKey.html">Enter Key</a></li>
    <li><a href="www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/">SO</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("a").filter(function(){
  return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
 }).after("<img src='/images/extlink.gif'/>");
});
</script>
```

Only first (Google) and last (SO) links show image not the thrid (MS) one.

Comment: Bear in mind the third one is not a valid external URL. It will end up within the current directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the links are being written on the page with the www. in front, not relative links.  the

```
this.hostname !== location.hostname
```

is returning true.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below you can find external links using `$('a:external');`

```
(function($) {
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    external: function(o) {
        return o.hostname !== window.location.hostname && o.hostname;
    }
});
$.fn.external = function() {
    return this.filter(':external');
};
}(this.jQuery));
```

With regards to links starting with a protocol (http://) you should do this for all external links anyway, otherwise most browsers will treat it as an internal link and prepend the domain name.